# Opening a pop up relative to the user position

Tags: javascript, css

How can I make a pop up window (basically a hidden div with high z-index) open in the middle of the screen, even if the user scrolls down a bit:

- When I use `position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;` the pop up opens in the middle of the screen, but when the user scrolls down the page the window stays "stuck" in the middle of the page.
- When I use `position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;` the window is not "stuck", but it is not positioned in the middle of the screen (if a user scorlled down before opening it, the window opens at the beginning of the page and the user must scroll up to see it).

How can i achieve both goal? Open the pop up at the center relative to the user's current position, and un-stick it so after it is opens it.

(This kind of pop up can be seen on Facebook, when opening "friends list" or "attending/not attending list" in events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 600px; height: 400px; margin-left: -300px; margin-top: -200px;`
The important thing is for margin-left and margin-top to be negative half the value of width and height, to ensure that the popup is exactly in the middle of the screen.
Alternatively, you can use `position: absolute` and use JavaScript to set `style.top` to `(document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop + 100)+"px"` if you want it to stay in the same place on the document - I think this is the one you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You require Javascript on some level to do this, because you need to know the dimensions of the user's viewport.

You can either put Javascript into your CSS (NEVER DO THIS!!!), or you can create an actual Javascript that will handle the window scroll event.